# How to plot graphs with each ID having 4 sub-ID line graphs in plotly python?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I am trying to create an interactive plot using plotly px/go but couldn't figure out a way to solve this issue. I have a dataset that looks somewhat like this:
[Sample Data Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7ncY.png)

There are more than 10k rows in the actual data. I want to create graphs with plotly line graphs where
x= Column C (Datetime value)
y= Column D

I am trying to generate graphs for ID 1, 2..., n where each ID has 4 line graphs of 4 sub-IDs from column B.

I tried px.line but it is not coming up right. I am also trying to create a for loop that will generate graphs for IDs 1, 2, 3,... upto n but no luck. Another idea is to create dictionary with IDs as individual dataframes. I am new to plotly and still trying to figure out a way to resolve this. Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: @newbit0001 can you be a bit more specific? when you say it's not working right, what do you mean? does the figure not render, or does the figure not behave the way you expect? it would also be much easier to help you if you provide some code showing what you have tried so we can work with you what you have so far – thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I understand that your question is that you want the x-axis to be column C, the y-axis to be column D, the line color to be column A, and the line type to be column B, so I have created the code. The line color is Alphabet, which has the most colors available in plotly. As for the dashes of the lines, there are several, so I have set the type needed for column B in dictionary form. The data frames extracted in the loop process of column A are grouped by the values in column A, and each group can be hidden or displayed depending on the click of the legend.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px

colors24 = px.colors.qualitative.Alphabet

fig = go.Figure()

# dash style ("solid", "dot", "dash", "longdash", "dashdot", or "longdashdot")
dash_style = {'a': 'solid','b': 'dot','c': 'dash','d': 'longdash','f': 'dashdot'}

for i,a in enumerate(df['A'].unique()):
    dfa = df.query('A == @a')
    for b in df['B'].unique():
        dfb = dfa.query('B == @b') 
        fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
            mode='lines',
            x=dfb['C'],
            y=dfb['D'],
            line=dict(color=colors24[i], dash=dash_style[b]),
            legendgroup='A'+str(i),
            name=str(a)))

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: The purpose of this site is not to help you write code, you are expected to submit your own code that you are working on.